# Meteor template event Click not firing on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, meteor

This Meteor template event failed to fire on iphone but works find on Android phone and desktop browsers. Any suggestion how to fix this? thx

```
Template.footer.events({
  'click .footerItem': function (event) {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="footer">
  <footer class="footer-row">
    {{#each footerButtons}}
        <div class="footerItem" data-action={{this.action}}>{{this.label}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  </footer>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem like an odd answer but try adding the following css to the class 'footerItem':

```
.footerItem {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `data-action={{this action}}`?
That is creating a conflict with the click event.  Delete that part from your html and try again, the click should works on iPhone.